# Working around a long running process in Cucumber

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I have a general design problem regarding Cucumber-
I'm trying to build some cucumber scenarios around a specific external process that takes some time. Currently, the tests look like this:

```
Given some setup
When I perform X action
And do the external process
Then validate some stuff
```

I have a number of these tests, and it would be massively more performant if I could do the external process just once for all these scenarios.
The problem I'm running into is that it doesn't seem like theres any way to communicate between scenarios in cucumber.

My first idea was to have each test running concurrently and have them hit a wait and poll the external process to see if it's running before proceeding, but I have no way of triggering the process once all the tests are waiting since they can't communicate.

My second idea was to persist data between tests. So, each test would just stop at the point the process needs to be run, then somehow gets their CucumberContext to a follow up scenario that validates things after the process. However, I'd have to save this data to the file system and pick it up again, which is a very ugly way to handle it.

Does anyone have advice on either synchronizing steps in cucumber, or creating "continuation" scenarios? Or is there another approach I can take?

Comment: Does that external process have any footprint letting one know it has finished?

Comment: I can freely poll the status to see if it's running or not.

Comment: So why wouldn't your scenario just poll that and if it is not it would be started and if it is it would wait for the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can't communicate data between scenarios, nor should you try to. Each scenario (by design) is its own separate thing, which sets and resets everything.

Instead what you can do is improve the way you execute your external process so instead of doing it each time, you use the results of it being done once, and then re-use that result in future executions of the scenario.

You could change your scenarios to reflect this e.g.

```
Given I have done x
And the external process has been run for x
Then y should have happened
```

You should also consider the user experience of waiting for the external process. For new behaviours you could do something like

```
When I do x
Then I should see I am waiting for the external process
```

and then later do another scenario

```
Given I have done x
And the external process has completed
Then I should see y
```

You can use something like VCR to record the results of executing your external process. (https://rubygems.org/gems/vcr/versions/6.0.0)

Note: VCR is ruby specific, but I am sure you can find a java equivalent.

Now that your external process executes pretty much instantly (a few milliseconds) your no longer have any need to share things between scenarios.